# Create groupRows with SXSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, grouping

Reading https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFSheet.html#groupRow(int,%20int)

it says that groups should be created inside window size, but how to create groups that overpass window size

Answer (score 0):

This minimal example generates a groupRow from row 2 to row 554 in a excel of 1000 rows with a window size of 200

```java
public static final int ROWS=1000;
public static final int WINDOW_SIZE=100;
//public static final int WINDOW_SIZE=1000;

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    File outputFile = new File("testFile-actual.xlsx");
    SXSSFWorkbook sworkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(WINDOW_SIZE);
    creatXLSX(outputFile, sworkbook);

    File expectedoutputFile = new File("testFile-expected.xlsx");
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    creatXLSX(expectedoutputFile, workbook);
}

private static void creatXLSX(File outputFile, Workbook workbook)
    throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
    int posFirstRow = 1;
    boolean addgroup = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        Row row = sheet.createRow(i);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(i);
        if (addgroup && i % WINDOW_SIZE == 0) {
            sheet.groupRow(posFirstRow, i);
            posFirstRow = i+1;
        }
        if (i == 556) {
            sheet.groupRow(posFirstRow, 553);
            posFirstRow = 556;
            addgroup = false;
        }
    }
    workbook.write(new FileOutputStream(outputFile));
}
```

Key is that:

```
groupRow(1,n)
groupRow(n+1, m)
```

joins two groups and generate same as

```
groupRow(1,m)
```

more info here https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58077